# How to create a view-only wallet for the GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, cold-storage, viewkey

Say I have a cold storage wallet, is there any way I can make a view only wallet with GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GUI can now create view only wallets. I've not used the GUI in a while, so I'm unable to give detailed steps, however. <s>Please someone who knows post an answer :)</s> See JollyMort's answer below, I can't delete an accepted answer.

Original answer is now obsolete, as pointed out below:

<s>The GUI does not support view only wallets yet.</s>

However, if you don't really care about having a correct balance, and just want to see incoming transfers (ie, not see spends), you should be able to load a view only wallet made by monero-wallet-cli into the GUI. There may be glitches.

Comment: Has this answer changed since January 1? Will the upcoming mobile apps offer this functionality?

Comment: It has. I'll update the answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible since `monero-gui-0.10.3.1-beta2` release.

Open your wallet from the GUI, and in the **Settings** tab you have the **Create view only wallet** button.

[image]

Click on it, and a window will show up letting you choose the name of the view-only wallet file and its location.

[image]

Give it a password,

[image]

and you will see a confirmation that it has been created.

[image]

Comment: tats creating a *new* wallet in view only mode, but how do you load up your view pub and spend pub keys into it?

Answer (score 2):

you can also import your private keys, and leave out the private spend key. **the result will be a view only wallet**

see here for details on how to do that:

[How to restore a Monero wallet from Private Keys](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/how-to-restore-a-monero-wallet-from-private-keys/3776#3776)