# How to restore a Monero wallet from Private Keys

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet-recovery

How can one import a Monero wallet via Private Keys (from mymonero.com / moneroaddress.org for example) into the GUI wallet? Is there a possible way via Private Spend- and View-Key?

Answer (score 15):

Importing a wallet from MyMonero into [monero-wallet-gui](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) is easy.

Follow these Steps:

1. Go to mymonero.com, access your account and navigate to Account Details. it will look like this:

[image: MyMonero account details]

2. Open Monero-wallet-gui and choose the 2nd Option:

[image: Restore from seed]
[image: Select restore from seed]

3. Now Enter you Account Details from mymonero.com. As `Restore height`, use the height of the first transaction to your wallet minus 20k. Thus, if the first transaction to your wallet was included in block `1350000`, use `1330000` as restore height. You can check the height of the first transaction to your wallet by entering the transaction ID / hash in a block explorer like, for instance, [XMRchain](https://xmrchain.net).

[image: Add seed restore info]

4. Now you can click the Next Button and set a password for your wallet.
5. On the next page, click "use monero" and you are ready to go.

Please Note:

- If you only use your Private View Key, a View-only wallet will be created.
- This Feature is only available in monero-wallet-gui beta 2 and higher.
- You need to sync up with the network so you can see your transactions and balance.
- If you want to use a remote node, use [this guide](https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html).

Comment: With GUI Beta 1, you could use [this alternative](http://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3091) for the time being.