# Problem Restoring Wallet from the Monero GUI, Right Arrow Greyed Out

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mymonero

My Monero wallet shows 0 XMR. I'm trying to recover it by restoring it from the GUI.  After inputting my address and keys, the right arrow is greyed out so I'm unable to get to the next screen to continue my wallet restore.  It happens on both options--"restore from seed" and "restore from keys".  Does anyone know why? I don't know the restore height but that says it's optional anyway. I'm using the Windows 64 bit version 0.11.1.0 Helium Hydra.

Comment: Can you count the words? Do you have 25 words? Also, which language is your seed in?

Comment: dEBRUYNE, Thank you so much for your comment!  I really appreciate your help!  No I don't have 25 words.  I only have 13 words in my Private login key.  My seed is in English.  I know this wasn't safe, but I snapped a picture of my private login key after I created my wallet and there's only 13 words there.  I do have my address, view key, and spend key and it was also greyed out when I tried those as well.

Comment: Which wallet / website did you use to create these 13 words?

Comment: I used mymonero.com.  I created a new wallet from their site to see how many words and it gave me a 13 word key again.

Comment: You should be able to use this guide then: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/how-to-restore-a-monero-wallet-from-private-keys. Let me know if it still greys out thereafter.

Comment: I tried using the guide to restore the wallet on my PC but I got stuck, so I switched to OS operating system.  Using the wallet-cli, per the instructions, I got to one of the last steps, which was opening the wallet through a file but all the files were greyed out so I must not have done it right.  I was to create a "suitable directory for the wallet" so I made a folder in my documents but when I tried to open the wallet from the file, it didn't open.  I think my issue is with something related to creating the right directory for the wallet because I was able to enter my address, & keys in CLI

Comment: Does your name contain a special character?

Comment: Nope,  OMG it's working!! It's syncing!!  It has1.4 mil blocks to go but it's working.  My problem was that I didn't change the name in the location of my hard drive where the wallet would be stored.  That was it.  I'm not done yet, but dEBRUYNE, if this works, because you were so helpful (and nice) I'd like to gift you a little XMR.  Please send your address so I can transfer you a bit once I'm able to.  Thank you so much for saving me!!!!  By the way, I flip houses in Vegas.  If there's anything I can ever do for you, let me know!  Is ok to give you my email address here?

Comment: All right. Good to hear you got it working. It has to fully sync first in order for you to see your funds. Note that, in Monero, there's two "syncs". First, the blockchain sync, which is basically downloading the blockchain from other nodes / peers. Second, the wallet sync, which is the wallet "refreshing" / scanning blocks looking for transactions belonging to your address / wallet. The GUI currently uses the same status bar for both syncs, which can be a bit confusing. Thus, if you see the `Blocks remaining:` starting all over again, it's the wallet refreshing.

Comment: In addition, you can use this guide for general usage of the GUI: https://medium.com/@Electricsheep56/the-monero-gui-wallet-broken-down-in-plain-english-bd2889b8c202. If you incur any issues, please leave a comment in this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7hhgjx/monero_gui_01110_helium_hydra_megathread_download/. Lastly, a reward / gift won't be necessary and you can PM your email address to my [reddit account](https://www.reddit.com/user/dEBRUYNE_1/) if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. When I unclicked both "stagenet" and "testnet" the arrow became available.