# MyMonero blockchain is behind

Tags: mymonero, web-wallet

For the last 10 days my mymonero wallet has not let me withdraw. It says the blockchain is behind and catching up, but every day its further behind so my XMR are trapped. What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The MyMonero web wallet's infrastructure is behind on syncing to the Monero network, scanning your wallet, or both. Luckily, MyMonero is only an interface to the network. You can access your funds through another mechanism by [following these steps](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3775/how-to-restore-a-monero-wallet-from-private-keys).