# Anyway to watch my own monero address without installing the full monero wallet?

Tags: viewkey, block-explorer, balance, view-only

Is there a way to monitor my monero address without the need to download the entire blockchain? And I don't want to constantly paste my private view key into a block explorer to see it neither. I want it to be able to just click a button or visit a link and be able to see my balance from time to time. What solutions are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the official GUI and set up a view-only wallet, without downloading the entire blockchain. You would still have to sync your wallet with the network. This doesn't take a long time.
[Connecting to remote node](https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html) - so you don't have to download the blockchain.
[Set-up a view-only wallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4582/1417)

Comment: for a view only wallet, how much of the blockchain is downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://mymonero.com) is a online monero wallet, it works for me.

Comment: u mean mymonero.com ?